# Automatically assign value to dictionary

Tags: list, function, dictionary

I'm still a beginner guys, so I don't know if what I'm doing is right...

In the code below I have a global Dictionary for player 1 and player 2. I then have a Function whereby player 1 chooses if he wishes to play as "x" or "o"... he/she is then assigned the choice, is there a way for me to automatically assign the opposite choice to the other player?

If this is a silly question, I apologize, I don't know

```
player1 = {"key1" : " "}
player2 = {"key2" : " "} 

def start_game():

    print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe')

    y = input("Player 1, select your marker (x/o): ")

    only_choice = ['x', 'o']
    
    if y in only_choice:
        player1['key1'] = y
```

Comment: hey! welcome to SO. In the if statement after you assign ```player1['key1']=y``` you can remove the element chosen by player1 by ```only_choice.remove(y)``` and then assign ```only_choice[0]``` to player2

Comment: amazing, thank you. It worked beautifully